# apt-key: line 352: comm: command not found

Tags: yocto, apt

I am building a linux image using yocto which support deb package manager(apt-get). I created the repo with packages and i want to authorize this repo to my target machine. i followed [these steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CreateAuthenticatedRepository) for that purpose. I created the keyFile successfully for the server (host). and when transfer this keyFile to my target and execute apt-key add keyFile, it promotes me the error

> /usr/bin/apt-key: line 352: comm: command not found

i use yocto pyro 17.0.1 and i built for core-image-sato plus adding the recipe gnupg which exist in meta/recipes-support/gnupg

Why this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the dependency on comm is missing. I believe this is part of coreutils, so add that to the image.

If that fixes it then a patch would be appreciated.

Comment: adding coreutils recipe to image solved the problem and the apt-key added the file.